# Rails turbo_stream being diverted to HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

The following Rails 7 form and its HTML rendering, running `turbo-rails 1.4`:

```
<%= form_with url: search_loop_results_individuals_path do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_field 'q', style: 'display: inline-block; width: 75%' %>
   <%= form.submit t('search') %>
 <% end %>

<div id="search_results">

</div>
...
<form action="/individuals/search_loop_results?locale=en" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="blurb" autocomplete="off" />
        <input style="display: inline-block; width: 75%" type="text" name="q" id="q" />
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="search" data-disable-with="search" />
</form>
<div id="search_results">

</div>
```

is logging

```
Started POST "/individuals/search_loop_results?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-15 11:55:32 +0200
Processing by IndividualsController#search_loop_results as TURBO_STREAM
```

The controller action executes

```
  def search_loop_results
    @individuals = Individual.where("name_last ILIKE ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%" ).or(Individual.where("name_first ILIKE ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%" )).page params[:page]
  end
```

and the log shows the search can be effected to populate a partial

```
  Rendering individuals/search_loop_results.html.erb within layouts/application
  Individual Count (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "individuals" WHERE (name_last ILIKE '%ludi%' OR name_first ILIKE '%ludi%')
  ↳ app/views/individuals/_index_for_assignment.html.erb:5
```

However, Rails will hit an error if the file is called `search_loop_results.turbo_stream.erb` with `ActionController::UnknownFormat (IndividualsController#search_loop_results is missing a template for this request format and variant.`.  If named  `search_loop_results.html.erb` the process completes, but in an unexpected way. The app processes the partial and iterates through the collection of results

```
 Rendering individuals/search_loop_results.html.erb within layouts/application
  Individual Count (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "individuals" WHERE (name_last ILIKE '%ludi%' OR name_first ILIKE '%ludi%')
  ↳ app/views/individuals/_index_for_assignment.html.erb:5
```

but then proceeds to process the request as if it were not a turbo stream and processes the file

```
  Rendered individuals/_index_for_assignment.html.erb (Duration: 27.7ms | Allocations: 9651)
  Rendered individuals/search_loop_results.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 29.3ms | Allocations: 10025)
```

with the browser console re-iterating the problem:

```
XHR  POST http://localhost:3000/individuals/search_loop_results?locale=en
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 129ms]

Error: Form responses must redirect to another location
```

Why is rails not following the standard pattern of launching a turbo_stream action and forcing a full HTML object?

**update**

attempted in the controller:

```
#    respond_to do |format|
#      format.turbo_stream do
         render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace('search_results', partial: 'individuals/index_for_assignment', class: 'fade-in-div') 
#      end
#    end
```

*The respond_to block is tautological and rails complains of being called to respond too often. commented out*

Left with the line to execute `render` the process completes, iterates through a (correct) collection of results and sends a correct response (as seen in the browser console with raw=true)
[image: raw=true]
however that response is not replacing the dom_id (and thus with the flag raw=false returns null
[image: raw=false])
and browser expects to go somewhere else.
[image: browser console complaint about destination]

This is different from standard behaviour without browser console complaints:
[image: no browser console complaints]

**update2**
This is a search query and not a requests that creates any changes to the db.  Thus it is akin to a get request and should be constructed accordingly.
As turbo streams were not initially intended for GET requests, this should be addressed via a turbo frame.  Which is executable as intended by the framework.

*leaving the question here, should someone encounter similar difficulties*

Comment: If you want the server to respond with to form submission with a stream you need to set the content type header in the response to `text/vnd.turbo-stream.html`. https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#streaming-after-a-form-submission. You can do this with MimeResponds - `format.turbo_stream`.

Comment: However it's not really clear in the question what your asking. "forcing a full HTML object" doesn't make sense. Are you talking about replacing the content in a stream or forcing a full page reload?

Comment: I am aiming for a content replacement.  What is most disconcerting is that the usual pattern where ` as TURBO_STREAM` is sent, should be naturally invoking a `.turbo_stream.erb` file and replacing/appending/prepending some dom_id from there.

Comment: Then you want to use `format.turbo_stream`. I'm not 100% sure about this but what what I think is happening is that implicit rendering is kicking in and Rails will look for the `.html.erb` template and send a `text/html` response code even if the request format was TURBO_STREAM.

Comment: Remember that turbo is built around the typical Rails CRUD controller where a form submission either redirects on success or renders explicitly on failure.

Comment: Right.  I went around that block but did not want to muddy the question.  Now it is updated.  I clearly do not see how to properly execute the dcall

Comment: In that first HTML example do you actually have `<div id="search_results">` twice on the same page or is that supposted to be two different views? Duplicate ids are not permitted in HTML and the results can be unreliable.

Comment: no.  the first is the rails code, the second half is the rendered HTML

Comment: "rails complains of being called to respond too often" - that should not happen, you should be able to use `respond_to` in any action, sounds like you're calling it already somewhere. Your request is TURBO_STREAM, your template is turbo_stream.erb and you get UnknownFormat - really looks like a respond_to call somewhere without format.turbo_stream, or if rendering implicitly "Template lookup accounts for the action name, locales, format, variant, template handlers, and more" https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ImplicitRender.html i see `?locale=en`   not sure how that relates.